# UITableView prepareForSegue assigning indexPath to sender?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, segue

In the code below I am just trying out setting up a segue directly from the `UIViewController` to a `DetailViewController`. I usually do the segue from the `UITableViewCell` (which I think is clearer) but this time I just wanted to try going directly from the `ViewController` using `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

**My question is:** I got to a situation where I needed to access the `UITableViewCell` `indexPath` from within `-prepareForSegue:sender:` my solution was to send the `indexPath` via `sender`. Usually I would set sender to `self` here, I have looked around and I can't find any reference to this, I am just curious if using sender to pass an indexPath is acceptable? I am pretty sure it is, and I am sure I have read that you can somewhere before, but I can't find any reference to it now.

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **
// DELEGATE: UITableView
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGUE_TWO" sender:indexPath];
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **
// SEGUE: ViewController_ONE > DetailViewController
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SEGUE_TWO"]) {
        NSUInteger cellRow = [(NSIndexPath *)sender row];
        DetailViewController *destinationController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [destinationController setDataString:[[self dataList] objectAtIndex:cellRow]];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** What I was looking for in this case was

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

essentially a way to get `indexPath` into `-performForSegue:sender:` without having to pass it via the sender parameter (in `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`)

Comment: In similar situations I tried the same and set the sender to another object than `self`. It did work in my case. I am not sure wether this is advisable. That's why I comment on it and don't write an answer. But it worked for me. Of course I did test wether the object really is what I expected before I typecasted and used it. However, it could be cleaner if you invent an iVar `indexPathUsed` or so and acces that in `prepareForSegue:` .

Comment: That is the other part of my question, as noted by @Answerbot in this case indexPathForSelectedRow allows you to access the indexPath directly without having to pass anything. I am sure I have seen other objects passed via sender (other than self) but I can also see how this might give rise to potential confusion when reading the code. My guess would be its possible where there is a need because the API is lacking, but not recommended.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I typically avoid using the sender in `prepareForSegue:` because it could be *anything*. This makes asserting that your sender is what you are expecting more cumbersome and fragile. Also, I prefer to check for the class of the destinationViewController object rather than the segue name. Your functionality is tied to your object (or more specficially its interface), not the title of your segue, so checking your class makes it clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Below is the usual template I use in production when segueing from a `UITableView`. Note that you should *always* check if the destinationViewController is embedded in a nav controller and then check the class of the object as well to make sure you are handling it correctly. Finally, use an assert to ensure that somewhere down the line you haven't added some new segue that you forgot to handle.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // unwrap the controller if it's embedded in the nav controller.
    UIViewController *controller;
    UIViewController *destVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([destVC isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) 
    {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)destVC;
        controller = [navController.viewControllers firstObject];
    } 
    else 
    {
        controller = destVC;
    }

    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]]) 
    {
        DetailViewController *vc = (DetailViewController *)controller;
        NSIndexPath *ip = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [vc setDataString:[[self dataList] objectAtIndex:ip.row]];

    } 
    else 
    {
        NSAssert(NO, @"Unknown segue. All segues must be handled.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use UITableView's method `indexPathForCell`. I hope you have a tableView instance variable.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is essentially the way I usually do this. But in this situation (as per the presented code) it would not work as sender would be a DetailViewController (a subclass of UIViewController). This is because the segue originates from the ViewController and not the UITableViewCell (as your code infers).